# Why Smarty does not work in the nested loop?

Tags: php, smarty

When I try to loop over this array

```
 {foreach $features_names as $k=>$label}                     
      {(isset($product['features'][$k])) ? $product['features'][$k]['value'] : '-'}
    {/foreach}
```

It works fine.

But when I put it into another loop it does not print me anything.

```
{foreach $compared_products as $product}
    {foreach $features_names as $k=>$label}                     
      {(isset($product['features'][$k])) ? $product['features'][$k]['value'] : '-'}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Why?

Comment: which error do you have?

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump(compared_products);` ?

Comment: how can I do var_dump in the smarty template?

Comment: {$variable|@var_dump}